# Sudo Through IPA Doesn't Allow Install Via Software Center

Tags: software-center

We manage sudo through IPA, and while this works fine at the command line, installing an app through the Software Center produces a permissions error. The current workaround is to move 'sss' to the front of the list on lines in the /etc/nsswitch.conf file. Is this the correct way to resolve this issue?